# After ListView onClick,change activity

Tags: android, listview, android-activity

Here's my code

```
this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
Intent i = new Intent(this,lastview.class);    
startActivity(i);
}
});
```

the "this" is a ListActivity,but I want the next activity is a normal activity

and my code is wrong in this line

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,lastview.class);
```

the wrong message is

```
 The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<lastview>) is undefined
```

how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the sample code .This will help you.

```
public class YourListActivity extends ListActivity {

private Context context;
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
super.onCreate(icicle);

 context =this;

  .....
  ......

 this.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
  Intent i = new Intent(context,lastview.class);   
   // else you can use the code like below    
  //Intent i = new Intent(YourListActivity.this ,lastview.class);   

  startActivity(i);
 }
});

}
```

Comment: thanks a lot   ^^

the problem solved by your answer

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

change this line

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,lastview.class);
```

like this, change your activity to MyListActivity

```
Intent i = new Intent( MyListActivity.this, lastview.class);
```

Comment: still wrong message..

and the message this time is like this

`No enclosing instance of the type ListActivity is accessible in scope`

Comment: Change activity name to MyListActivity.. see my answer now.

Comment: which activity name do you mean...?

the lastview?

or the activity first?

Comment: the problem solved^^

bur still thanks for your help^^

thanks a lot!

you're all God in coding..^^

Answer (score 0):

You can also write it like :

```
startActivity(new Intent(Yourclass_name.this,lastview.class));
```